# APCu PHP extension Mac OS X loaded but dont work

Tags: php, macos, apache2, apc, php-extension

I have a problem with installing APCu on Mac OS X El Capitan. I have installed APCu by command:

```
brew install php55-apcu
```

There was no problemm during installation, but after restarting my server (apache2) I cant see APCu block in phpinfo(). I should see something like this: [Phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beq2D.png) (its not mine screen)

The apcu.so file is loaded correctly. My phpinfo is shown here: [Phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWD5K.png). Ext-apcu.ini file exists, and this is its content:

```
[apcu]
extension="/usr/local/opt/php55-apcu/apcu.so"
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=64M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli=1
```

As you can see, its loading apcu.so file - this file exists and was generated (i think correctly) during installation by *brew*.

I did the same while Opcache installation and it works properly, but APCu do not.

Comment: Same issue - did you resolve?

Comment: No :( I dont remember how I replaced APCu but Im sure I didnt installed apcu properly :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding these two lines to **php.ini**,

```
apc.enabled=1
apc.enable_cli=1
```

If only the first line is set, it does not works.

For macOS, the php.ini is normally located in `/usr/local/etc/php/<version>/php.ini` and you can check by `$ php -i | grep ini`

```sh
$ php -i | grep ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
```

Finally, check if apc is enabled

```sh
$ php -i | grep apc
apc.enable_cli => On => On
apc.enabled => On => On
```

See for more https://www.php.net/manual/en/apcu.configuration.php